# Get Label ID to get a List of Messages with GMAIL API

Tags: java, api, gmail

I am using the new GMAIL API v1 that Google launched some days ago.

I want to get the list of some emails filtering with some labels. If I want to do that, I need to get the **label ID** of each "label_name" but I just can get the list of all of labels...

Any idea?

Diego.

Answer (score 9):

Label ID is the same as Label Name only for system generated labels. For example CHAT, SENT, INBOX, TRASH, etc.

User-generated labels have IDs that are different from their names.

The easiest way to get them is to use the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list#try-it) that imCaps mentioned.

Alternatively, you can use this

```
function listLabels() {
  var request = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me');
  var name, id;
  for (var l = 0 ; l < request.labels.length; l++) {
    name = request.labels[l].name;
    id = request.labels[l].id;
    Logger.log("%s. %s %s", l, name, id)
  }
}
```

You'll need to enable the Gmail API in Advanced Google Services for this code to work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have used:

```
ListMessagesResponse messagesWithLabels = service.users().messages().list("me").setQ("label:mylabel").execute();
```

It is working :)

Answer (score 1):

LABEL ID is the same LABEL NAME.

```
{
   "id": "INBOX",
   "name": "INBOX",
   "messageListVisibility": "hide",
   "labelListVisibility": "labelShow",
   "type": "system"
  }
```

try here [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list#try-it) with your credentials.

Comment: Only for system labels. User generated labels have unique IDs